# Passing generic type as a parameter in java?

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to save a Type in a variable, 
in order to instantiate a List of this type?

```
//something like that
Type type = Boolean;
List<type> list = new List<type>();
list.add(true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first requirement, you are looking for [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

```
Class type = Boolean.class;
```

However, I don't think the seconds requirement is feasible, since generic types only exist at compile time:

```
List<type> list = new List<type>(); // invalid code
```

You can, however, work with `List<Object>`. It will accept `Boolean` objects. Whether this will buy you anything untlimately depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Generic is a compile time feature, not run time, so you cannot use variable to determine the generic type, even using NPE's note (using `Class`) will not compile:

```
Class<?> type = Boolean.class;
// can't do that...
List<type> list = new List<type>();
list.add(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

In second case why do you want to use generics when type is unknown? You can better use non-generic arraylist ( used before jdk 5).

```
   List a = new ArrayList();
   a.add(object);
```

This style is still supported by higher versions and even generics style gets converted to this form after compilation. You will get warning in above code which you can suppress.